# Solve ODE with parameters changing with state variable

Tags: python, ode

In my model I have several differential equations to be solved. However, the parameters of the differential equations are not constant over time, but they change depending on the to state variables (or other variables) over time.
How can I implement this using an ODE solver?

Here is the code for the charge of a capacitor `C` with a constant voltage `V_S` and a series resistance `R`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def f(v, t, R, C, V_S):
    dvdt = 1/R/C*(-v+V_S)
    return dvdt

C = 500*pow(10,-6) #Farad
R = 10
V_S = 10
t = np.linspace(0,0.04,999)
v0 = 0

v = odeint(f, v0, t, args=(R, C, V_S))
i = (V_S - v)/R
```

How can I solve the equation assuming that parameter `R` changes with time according to:
*R*(*t*) = *R*<sub>1</sub>·sin(*v*(*t*)) + *R*<sub>2</sub>·cos(*i*(*t*)),
with *R*<sub>1</sub> and *R*<sub>2</sub> being constants to be tuned.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a parameter, `R` becomes something that you need to compute on the fly when evaluating your derivative. Things become a bit more complicated as you have as `R` depends on `i` which in turn depends on `R`. Thus, determining `R` requires you to numerically solve an equation on every step. Still, this can be done:

```
def f(v, t, R_1, R_2, C, V_S):
    R_eq = lambda R: R_1*np.sin(v) + R_2*np.cos((V_S - v)/R) - R
    R = scipy.optimize.root_scalar(R_eq)
    dvdt = 1/R/C*(-v+V_S)
    return dvdt
```

Mind that I haven’t tested this. You may need to help `root_scalar` by providing an initial guess of `R` to make it converge faster, at all, or to the same solution every time.